# Why href does not work on server in app react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, href

I am creating a project in react but I came across a problem when creating the responsive menu. That is, when using a menu that uses href it does not work on the apache server and Link To does not solve my problem. I have this code:

```
  return (
<div>
    <ResponsiveMenu
        menuOpenButton={<FaBars size={30} color="MediumPurple" />}
        menuCloseButton={<FaRegWindowClose size={30} color="MediumPurple" />}
        changeMenuOn="500px"
        largeMenuClassName="large-menu"
        smallMenuClassName="small-menu"
        menu={
            <Menu>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">INICIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/project">PROJETO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/partners">PARCERIA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/products">PLANTAS & LÃ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/resources">RECURSOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contacts">CONTACTOS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </Menu>
        }
    />
</div>
);
```

Comment: Please include more information about the errors you're seeing

Comment: It only appears that you can not find a page. When I put the app in production on an Apache server with HREF it does not find the pages. However, LINK To works correctly. But with LINK TO the menu is not completely responsive

Comment: You may have to include more details about your directory structure on the server then. Make sure there are actual files in the directories you're linking to.

Comment: I'm directed to the href only with / page